# css is not being applied

Tags: html, css

I am using Visual Studio to code my website (non-online). While trying to implement css into my html code, the color background I am trying add doesn't show up on the website. I have run the code in stack overflow and it worked as intended, but it will not work in my browser. (I have already tried removing caches from chrome from the last hour and have tried using incognito mode, IE, ME, and Brave to no avail)

```css
#header {
 background-color: #66CCFF;
 }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <link rel="styesheet" type="text/css" href="testlook.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="header">
    <h1>My Test</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="content">
    <div id="nav">
     <h3>Navigation</h3>
      <ul>
       <li>Home</li>
       <li>About</li>
       <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
     <h2>Home page</h2>

     <p>Paragraph 1, 360 days in a day. So that's cool.</p>
     <p>Paragraph 2, 365 days in a day. So that's cool.</p>
     <p>Paragraph 3, 360 days in a day. So that's nic.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div="footer">
    Copyright &copy; Test
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check developer tools to see if there is any error on console, regarding some file not being loaded

Comment: check for loaded css too, sometimes if you are using 3rd party css, they put some nasty `!important` flags

Comment: Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Also @Rob check this, also doesn't include research I was doing on my chromebook before it died (https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1vVGB3OMh5XUKu4KfuFpk4A73glZF02eVF9fnTa-vAzo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `rel="styesheet"` in your **link** to your **testlook.css** file.

It should be `rel="stylesheet"` to be valid.

Not having a valid value in the `rel` attribute interferes with accessing the file correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not sure how I missed that

Answer (score -1):

Stylesheet is misspelled in the link and this is causing the styling to not be applied.

Answer (score -1):

- If you're using chrome you can disable the cache in the network tab,
  "Disable Cache (while DevTool is open)". You can probably do the same with Firefox and others browser of course.
- Check if you load correctly your css in your html in your console, you should have an error if something can't be loaded.
- Your link might be broken because of your `rel="styesheet"`, it should be `rel="stylesheet"`

Comment: Thank you for the useful info on chrome, I didn't know that! Have a great day